# python os.walk returns nothing

Tags: python

I have a problem with using `os.walk` on Mac. If I call it from `python terminal`, it works perfect, but if I call it via a `python script`, it returns empty list. For example:

```
    import os

    path = "/Users/temp/Desktop/test/"
    for _ ,_ , files in os.walk(path):
        test = [my_file for my_file in files]

    print test
```

then, it prints:

```
    []
```

and I am pretty sure that the `path` does exists.
Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: looks like you are missing an s in your list comprehension. `test = [my_file for my_file in files]`

Comment: Try absolute path instead of relative path

Comment: @miah: Sorry, it is a typo, it is correct in my code

Comment: @DineshPundkar: you mean `os.path.abspath(path)`? I tried that, it does not work either.

Comment: Every iteration is creating a new list, and then you're discarding it. Only the value of the last iteration is being held. Try putting a print statement within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to intantiate the test list outside the for loop, for this to work.

```
import os

path = "/Users/temp/Desktop/test/"
test = []
for _ ,_ , files in os.walk(path):
    test.extend([my_file for my_file in files])

print test
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now!, why do I need to use `extend`?

Comment: [extend](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) adds all the elements in the list to the other list